# Django ORM - Annotate Query with another SubQuery while keeping the results of SubQuery

Tags: mysql, django, orm, prefetch, annotate

```
#  My Database Models
ModelA(models.Model):
    referancer = models.CharField()
    ...
        
ModelXYZ(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
```

I have models like top and there is no foreignkey relation between them also structure should stay this way because in my real query; filters and annotations are more complexier then this one. Also this is simplest way to reproduce problem.

```
modelXYZ_subquery = ModelXYZ.objects.filter(name__exact=OuterRef('referancer')).order_by('-id')
modelA_dataset = ModelA.objects.filter(**my_custom_filters).annotate(
    has_XYZ=Exists(modelXYZ_subquery),
    latest_xyz=Subquery(modelXYZ_subquery.values('id')[:1], output_field=IntegerField)
)

for _modelA in modelA_dataset:
    my_custom_function_1(_modelA)
    if _modelA.has_XYZ:
        detected_xyz = ModelXYZ.objects.get(id=_modelA.latest_xyz) # Database Hit
    else:
        detected_xyz = create_xyz(_modelA)
    my_custom_function_2(_modelA, detected_xyz)
```

This is the function I got but its working for too long because of the huge dataset.

**I want to get rid of the unnecessarry database hit I got top there in for loop.**

Is there anyway to achive this goal with **annotation** or **prefetch_related** or something?

Comment: Why is this field `referancer` then not a **`ForeignKey`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using [JoinField](https://github.com/martsberger/django-joinfield). This will not change your database structure, but will allow the ORM to do joins the same way it does with foreign keys. `pip install django-joinfield` and put `joinfield` in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
from joinfield.joinfield import JoinField

class ModelXYZ(models.Model):
    name = JoinField(ModelA, to_field='referancer', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

makemigrations will create a migration, but the migration will not change your database structure. It will be allowed to have values in ModelXYZ.name that don't exist in ModelA.referancer.

Now you can do a `prefetch_related` from ModelA to ModelXYZ.

Comment: I will wait for the last day of bounty. If there is no better answer then I will edit my question and approve this as an answer sir.